# Database Schema for News System

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, schema

I have a news system I'm designing, and it seemed straight-forward at first, but as I've pushed forward with my planned schema I've hit problems... Clearly I haven't thought it through. Can anyone help?

The system requires that the latest 20 news articles be grabbed from the database. It's blog-like in this way. Each article can have sub-articles (usually around 3) that can be accessed from the parent article. The sub-articles are only ever visible when the parent article is visible -- they're not used elsewhere.

The client needs to be able to hide/display news articles (easy), but also change their order, if they desire (harder).

I initially stored the sub-articles in a separate table, but then I realised that the fields were essentially the same: Headline, Copy, Image. So why not just put them all in one big table?

Now I've hit other problems around the ordering. It's Friday evening and my head hurts!

Can anyone offer advice?

Thanks.

---

**Update:** People have asked to see my "existing" schema:

```
articleID *   
headline  
copy
imageURL
visible
pageOrder

subArticleID *
articleID 
headline
copy
imageURL
visible
pageNumber
pageOrder
```

Will this work? How would I go about letting users change the order? It seemed the wrong way to do it, to me, so I threw this out.

Comment: You should post some examples as to what you've tried so far, and clarify what you're asking about. Right now, it sounds like you want someone to plan your database schema for you.

Comment: You should edit the question. Put your schema here.then ask what modifications should be done to achieve that goal. Make it more specific. I shouldn't be telling you this as you have 4 times more repo than me lol....

Comment: @Travesty3 Ok, I've added my existing schema

Comment: When people ask to see your schema, they usually want to see the SQL statements that create it. That way, they can paste the SQL DDL into their own editor and avoid the (annoying) effort of reverse-engineering your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I initially stored the sub-articles in a separate table, but then I realised that the fields were essentially the same: Headline, Copy, Image. So why not just put them all in one big table?

Because referential integrities are not the same.

That is, of course, if you want to restrict the tree to exactly 2 levels. If you want more general data model (even if that means later restricting it at the application level), then go ahead and make a general tree.

This would probably look something like this:

[image]

Note how both PARENT_ARTICLE_ID and ORDER are NULL-able (so you can represent a root) and how both comprise the UNIQUE constraint denoted by `U1` in the diagram above (so no two articles can be ambiguously ordered under the same parent).

Comment: Thanks! There will only ever be two levels, so this works. One problem: The MainArticle (as opposed to a SubArticle) can also be ordered. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Well, you can either imply the order based on the existing PK, or if that's not practical simply introduce an alternate key just for ordering.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Not at all. If they are NULL, they are simply ignored when enforcing the UNIQUE constraint, which is exactly what we need, to be able to have multiple "root" (i.e. parent-less) articles. I think MySQL had some crazy behavior for NULLs in UNIQUE constraints for some older storage engines, but the InnoDB will do the right thing similar to what every other DBMS does and exclude NULLs from UNIQUE enforcement. You can play with it in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5834b/8).

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've described. I would use two tables. The first table would hold all the articles and sub-articles. The second would tie the articles to their sub-articles.

The first table (call it `articles`) might have these columns:

```
+-----------+----------+------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| articleID | headline | copy | imageURL | visible | pageNumber | pageOrder |
+-----------+----------+------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

The second table (call it `articleRelationships`) might have these columns:

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| parentArticleID | childArticleID |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

Not sure if you already accomplish this with the `pageNumber` column, but if not, you could add a column for something like `articleLevel` and give it something like a 1 for main articles, 2 for sub-articles of the main one, 3 for sub-articles of a level 2 article, etc. So that way, when selecting the latest 20 articles to be grabbed, you just select from the table where `articleLevel = 1`.

I'm thinking it would probably also be useful to store a date/time with each article so that you can order by that. As far as any other ordering goes, you'll have to clarify more on that for me to be more help there.

To display them for the user, I would use AJAX. I would first display the latest 20 main articles on the screen, then when the user chooses to view the sub-articles for a particular article, use AJAX to call the database and do a query like this:

```
SELECT a.articleID, a.headline
FROM articles a
    INNER JOIN articleRelationships ar ON a.articleID = ar.childArticleID
WHERE ar.parentArticleID = ? /* ? is the articleID that the user clicked */
ORDER BY articleID
```

Answer (score 1):

> The client needs to be able to hide/display news articles (easy), but
>   also change their order, if they desire (harder).

On this particular point, you'll need to store client-specific ordering in a table. Exactly how you do this will depend, in part, on how you choose to deal with articles and subarticles. Something along these lines will work for articles.

```
client_id   article_id   article_order
-- 
1           1067         1
1           2340         2
1             87         3
...
```

You'll probably need to make some adjustments to the table and column names.

```
create table client_article_order (
  client_id integer not null,
  article_id integer not null,
  article_order integer not null,
  primary key (client_id, article_id),
  foreign key (client_id) references clients (client_id) on delete cascade,
  foreign key (article_id) references articles (article_id) on delete cascade
) engine = innodb;
```

Although I made article_order an integer, you can make a good case for using other data types instead. You *could* use float, double, or even varchar(n). Reordering can be troublesome.

---

If you don't need the client id, you can store the article ordering in the article's table.

But this is sounding more and more like the kind of thing Drupal and Wordpress do right out of the box. Is there a compelling reason to reinvent this wheel?

Comment: Thanks, but why is there a ClientID? There is only one client.

Comment: I thought "client id" referred to a person, and that there would be many persons using your data, each person having their own preferred order.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that idea :-/ There's only one order, set by the client.

Comment: Yes, there is a compelling reason.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new field in news(article) table "parent" which will contain news id of parent article. This new field will be used as a connection between articles and sub articles.

Answer (score 0):

As SlideID "owns" SubSlideID, I would use a composite primary key for the second table.

```
PrimaryKey: slideID, subSlideID
Other index: slideID, pageNumber, pageOrder   (Or however they get displayed)
```

One blog post I prefer to point out about this is http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx as it explains why very nicely.

If you're replying on Auto_Increment, that can be handled too (with MyISAM tables), you can still set subSlideID to auto_increment.

If you're likely to go to a third level then merge - follow Branko above. But it does start to get very complicated, so keep separate for 2 layers only.